# How does (sort {$a<=>$b;} @_)[0]; work?

Tags: perl

I once read the following Perl subroutine

```
sub min{
  (sort  {$a<=>$b;}  @_)[0];
}
```

How to understand the usage of sort and @_ here? What does [0] stand for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`(...)[0]` returns the first element of the list inside of the parentheses.

So your example is effectively the same as:

```
sub min{
  my @tmp = sort { $a <=> $b } @_; # sort numerically
  $tmp[0];
}
```

or

```
sub min{
  my ($return) = sort { $a <=> $b } @_; # sort numerically
  $return;
}
```

---

I would like to point out one more thing, the code above is wildly inefficient. Especially on large unsorted lists.

Here is a more sensible approach:

```
sub min{
  $min = shift;
  for( @_ ){
    $min = $_ if $_ < $min;
  }
  return $min;
}
```

This is basically the same algorithm used for the [Pure Perl](http://metacpan.org/source/GBARR/Scalar-List-Utils-1.23/lib/List/Util/PP.pm) version of [`min`](http://p3rl.org/List::Util#min-LIST) in [List::Util](http://p3rl.org/List::Util).

You really should just be using [`min`](http://p3rl.org/List::Util#min-LIST) from [List::Util](http://p3rl.org/List::Util).

Comment: Actually, if you look at the `PP` version of `List::Util::min`, it uses `reduce` which seems rather inefficient. Syntactically sweet, but unnecessarily adds another subroutine layer in the process.

Comment: @Zaid That is why I wrote *basically* the same. Most of the time you would actually use the [XS](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs.html) version of [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html), which would be much faster.

Comment: I'm totally with you, but it seems bizarre that for something as commonly used as `List::Util` (remember that sometimes `XS` simply isn't available) could be improved so much

Answer (score 3):

This numerically sorts the parameters to the sub (which are in the array @_) and returns the first element of the result (which is in [0]).  The first element is the minimum of all of the args.  It assumes they are all numeric.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is a rather inefficient way to find a minimum - this will run with at least `O(n lg n)` worst case, while you can write a minimum-finder with `O(n)` time

Comment: Can you add more details on this? Is that because the posted code uses a pair-wise comparison? Thanks.

Comment: Sorts take O(n lg n) time.  However, the minimum can be found by just racing through the list once, in O(n).  You don't need to do all of the work of a sort.

Comment: In >= 5.7 perl uses mergesort which is O(N lg n) - see http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html